# What is the right htaccess code for Php 7.4 redirect?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Can someone please help me redirect the php pages to html (only in the root directory, without subfolders)?  I tried dozens of solutions, but I didn't succeed. The code below redirects everywhere (including in subfolders...) I don't want the subdirectories to be affected.
My domain: https://www.example.com/
Thanks in advance!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>


<FilesMatch ".(ico|css|flv|js|gif|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|svg|ttf|webp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: `.` allows _every_ arbitrary character - including slashes. Replace that with a character group that allows for everything _but_ slashes.

Comment: Replace `.` with `[^./]`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Can you please help me assemble the final code?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Hello! Your code didn't worked, he is not redirecting php to html.

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# external redirect to .html from .php request
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^./]+?)\.php$ /$1.html [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# internal rewrite to .php from .html if corresponding php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]

<FilesMatch ".(ico|css|flv|js|gif|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|svg|ttf|webp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that `[^./]` will match any character that is not a dot and not a `/` thus matching only in root directory skipping all sub directories.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer! I got an error when i access https://www.example.com/test.html  This page isn’t working right now (HTTP ERROR 500)

Comment: This needs to replace all of your shown code. I have tested this exact code on my local apache and redirection/rewrite are all happening fine.

Comment: I tried your second code with Php 7.4 and i got the same result when i access example.com/page.html [This page isn’t working right now] can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: You need to check Apache error.log for reason of 500 error. May be there is some syntax error while copy pasting. As I wrote earlier that I have copied all of this code to my local apache and everything is working.

Comment: I restarted apache and your code worked great!  I use the couchcms script in the subfolder. How can I make the couchcms script not be affected in htaccess?
https://www.example.com/couchcms/    When i try to log in i get the following message: Cookies must be enabled to use this CMS ; Can I add an exception to the example.com/couchcms folder?

Comment: It is unlikely that existing rules are affecting `/couchcms/`. When you rename this site root .htaccess to something else (for testing) and then visit `https://www.example.com/couchcms/` does this error go away?